# use of BasicContextSelector in log4j2 configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

We are trying to introduce log4j2 in our project. We are looking to use common log4j configuration for all applications deployed in the tomcat container and we wish to use single logger context. I am expecting multiple applications logging to same log file.

Here is what we are doing to achieve this:

1. placing log4j2 jars and its dependencies in sharedclasspath of
   tomcat container.
2. placing the log4j2.xml in shared classpath.
3. Setting the Log4jContextSelector to "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector" value using system properties.

Is this setup correct?
Will this type of setup have any performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any issue with the configuration you described. You are essentially following one of the [recommended](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html) Log4j2 setups.

There should be no performance issues either. If your web apps experience activity bursts then I'd recommend using [Async Loggers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) to ensure the logging doesn't impact the performance of your applications.

Comment: thank you @remko for again resolving the queries quickly this was helpful . sorry for late acknowledgement.